# modifier function

Tags: solidity, remix

Can someone help me on what exactly the modifier is doing in this contract and why the message data length is increased by 4?

```
contract NonPayloadAttackableToken {
    modifier onlyPayloadSize(uint size) {
        assert(msg.data.length == size + 4);
        _;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) onlyPayloadSize(2 * 32) {
    // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+ 4` is because the hash of the function signature is 4 bytes, so the modifier is only checking the length of the function payload. This modifier seems to be validating that the msg is `size` bytes, ignoring the function signature.

Comment: Ok I figured. I just was not sure. The 4 bytes are used as a hash signature.

Comment: @S.Ansari if the answer is helpfull please consider to accept it

Comment: @BadrBellaj need to get more up to speed with stackexchange etiquette lol